Property has no setter
I have an error with my code saying:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Designer5.PUCCINI.000\Documents\pws256\pws256\src\__init__.py", line 116, in <module>
    pw.hsh_func = ""
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: property 'hsh_func' of '_Password' object has no setter

Here is my code:
class _Password:
    def __init__(self, hashed, hsh_func, hsh_enter, hsh_after, salt):
        self.hashed = hashed
        self._hsh_enter = hsh_enter
        self._hsh_func = hsh_func
        self._hsh_after = hsh_after
        self.__salt = salt

    @property
    def hsh_func(self):
        return self._hsh_func
    
    @hsh_func.setter
    def set_hsh_func(self, obj):
        if not isinstance(obj, function):
            raise TypeError(
                f"obj must be a function, not {obj.__class__.__name__}"
            )
        self._hsh_func = obj

    @property
    def salt(self):
        return self.__salt
    
    @property
    def hsh_after(self):
        return self._hsh_after
    
    @hsh_after.setter
    def set_hsh_after(self, obj):
        if not isinstance(obj, str):
            raise TypeError(
                f"obj must be of type 'str', not {obj.__class__.__name__}"
            )
    

    def validate(self, other: str):
        "Validate a password using the hsh_func entered on creation"
        print(hl.sha256(other.encode()).hexdigest(), self.salt)
        encoded = self.hsh_func(((self.salt + other) if self.hsh_enter == str else (self.salt + other).encode()))
        if self.hsh_after:
            encoded = eval("encoded" + self.hsh_after, dict({"encoded": encoded})) # Add hsh_after e.g. hashlib.sha256(b"hello").hexdigest()

        return encoded == self.hashed
    

pw = _Password(hashlib.sha256("hello".encode()).hexdigest(), hashlib.sha256, ".hexdigest()")
pw.hsh_func = hashlib.sha512


The setter methods need to have the same name, no set_ prefix.

@jonrsharpe The setter can have a different name, but then the different name also has to be used for setting. With the given code, p.set_hsh_func = "foo"; print(p.hsh_func) will work perfectly fine, i.e. it will print "foo" (I only removed the if not isinstance(…) for this to work). See, e.g. this answer to a related question.

@simon that's true, but it's relatively unusual to have a different setter than getter, and certainly not the OP's usage (hence their error).

@jonrsharpe Of course you are right in all your points. I just wanted to point out that OP's example actually works, although not in the way OP expected.

As a side note: You probably want to access all fields through their setters even in the __init__() method. At present, for example, p = _Password(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) can be instantiated, implying that self._hsh_func will now have the value 2, rather than being a function, as you desire. This is because it did not have to pass the setter's check of whether the given value is actually a function, which will only happen on subsequent attempts of setting self._hsh_func with a new value.

The Python decorator syntax:
@decorator
def function():
    ...

is syntactic sugar for:
def function():
    ...


function = decorator(function)

Similarly, using decorators inside the class:
class Foo:

    @property
    def bar(self):
        ...

    @bar.setter
    def set_bar(self, value):
        ...

becomes:
class Foo:

    def bar(self):
        ...

    bar = property(bar)

    def set_bar(self, value):
        ...

    set_bar = bar.setter(set_bar)
    # ^^^^^ - problem

This isn't necessarily wrong, as explained in Why do getter/setter methods have to have the same name(s) as name of original property? (thanks to simon for linking this in the comments), but does mean that bar itself doesn't have a setter - you'd need to assign to set_bar, not bar:
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.bar = 123
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
AttributeError: property 'bar' of 'Foo' object has no setter
>>> foo.set_bar = 456
>>>

However, what you generally want with a property is to get and set the same attribute. To make that work you need:
    bar = bar.setter(...)

which when using the decorator syntax means using the same name for the decorated method:
    @bar.setter
    def bar(self, value):
        ...


You're welcome @HectorRobertson, but please note https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
